# HTMLPurify - Disable Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I use HTMLPurify for disabling JavasSript in a textarea.

My problem is:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
$va = $purifier->purify($va);
```

This removes script tags, but does not remove `[a href='javascript:...']link[/a]`

What should I do to remove the bad links and retain good links?

Comment: `[a href='javascript:...']link[/a]` is not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [AllowedSchemes](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#URI.AllowedSchemes) whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

The live demo is indeed filtering both `href="javascript:...` and `onclick`. You can see the demo [here](http://bit.ly/bkUosR).

Maybe you are using an older version?

Comment: now its ok, the solution was;
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$config inside function, is a stupid problem, sorry

Answer (score -3):

Use regular expressions to scan the textareas content for invalid / unwanted tags.

Comment: No, with htmlpurify is possible see this page http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php, but I can not find where it explains.

Comment: Ok, that was not clear from your initial post (no reference to html purifier)

Comment: I count *three* references to it in version 1 of the question (having gone back and looked at the first revision)